# AWS ETL extraction from RDBMS/CSV

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I am trying to see what's best AWS tools anyone using for extraction like Step/Lambda/Glue/Athena etc

I got about 50 tables(Oracle to Redshift) and CSV' as source data
Looking to load Delta daily basis

Will it be better step functions with Lambda or Athena with Glue/Crawler/Python scripts to load data's ?

Trying to see best latest technologies we can use for extracting data daily basis

Comment: please take a look at my answer before this question most likely gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue excels at extracting data from csv files stored in s3 buckets and then loading them into the Glue Data Catalog. You would create a Crawler in Glue for the CSV extraction. If necessary, you can create a Classifier and associate it with the Crawler. When you run the Crawler, it will store the data as a schema in the Glue Catalog in a Glue database you specify. Inside that database will be metadata table definitions. You can peruse each table and view the generated schema, including data types that were generated from the original semi-structured data.

Then you will create a second Crawler, which will be a JDBC Crawler connecting to your Oracle database. This crawler will then pull the sql tables into the Glue Catalog as well. This JDBC Connection can be an RDS Instance or it can even be a database sitting in another aws account and you can establish a PrivateLink connection via a VPC Endpoint Service. You will need to create a Connection in Glue for the JDBC Crawler. THe connection specifies how to connect to the underlying database.

Once you have all your data in the database in your Data Catalog, then you can create an ETL Job, which uses Apache Spark ETL under the hood, but adds additional layer called Dynamic Frames, which sits on top of Spark Data Frames. You would use the PySpark ETL Script to build the ETL and migrate the data over. You can also query the s3 data in the data catalog using Athena. Inspect and analyze it with Athena using a sql like query language. This is where Athena excels.

All the services you listed have a use case and all are powerful. Hopefully this gives you some guidance in using the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, That was useful and what about delta or changes daily basis, Is there any specific CDC feature available in AWS?